# Progress bar Issue : End results not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, progress-bar

Im having an issue with my progress bar. Now I have looked through all of the questions in overflow and Ive been through alot of google searching. I may have overlooked something, but Ill bet you anything this problem is something really simply I keep overlooking. Heres the deal.

My progress bar seems to work just fine. Im using ajax, everything is in the right panel, it fires immediatly when the button is pushed and actually it stops once the process is completed (although I have no idea how I did that). Please note, this is as simple as it gets. Its just a GIF, nothing special. Using Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008, Ajax, and C#. Im not using a jquery or js, although I may have too.

My application is simple. It sends orders to a different server, so I am on the client side. Once the button is clicked, the orders are in the process of being sent. My Problem is, although the orders are being sent, when the progress bar stops, and the process is done, my labels (success or error) and order database tables do not fire. Why is this? I find this very odd because the application sends the orders, it functions 100%, but nothing changes on the user side.

Here is some code, if you need more then just say the word. Thank you all in advance!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Initialize();
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    KaplanFTP.BatchFiles bf = new KaplanFTP.BatchFiles();
    KaplanFTP.Transmit transmit = new KaplanFTP.Transmit();

    if (btn.ID == PutFTPButton.ID)
    {//code

    private void Initialize()
{//code   if success/notsuccess  labels will fire
```

Also here is the design code if it helps

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="mainPanel">
        <div>
            <h3>Number of Batches Created Today: <asp:Label runat="server" style="display:inline;" ID="BatchesCreatedLbl"></asp:Label></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="batchestoprocessdiv">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="BatchesToProcessLbl" Text="THERE IS AN ORDER BATCH TO PROCESS." CssClass="green"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="NoBatchesToProcessLbl" Text="There are no Order Batches to Process." CssClass="red" 
            Visible="false"></asp:Label>
             <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="PutFTPButton" runat="server" onclick="Button_Click" 
                    Text="Submit Orders" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <span class="red">COUNTDOWN TO SUBMISSION!</span>
        <span id="timespan" class="red">

        </span>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ErrorLabel" Visible="false" CssClass="red" Text="Error: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" 
            AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
<img alt="" class="style1" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="red" Height="16px" 
                    Text="Sending Orders....Please Wait"></asp:Label>
            </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="SuccessLabel" Visible="false" CssClass="green" Text="Batch has been processed and uploaded successfully."></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div id="OrdersInfoDiv" runat="server" visible="false">

        <asp:GridView ID="BatchDetails" Caption="Details of orders ready to be sent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
        CssClass="InfoTable" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="InfoTableAlternateRow" >
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div id="OrdersSentDiv" class="mainPanel" runat="server" visible="false">
        <h4>Sent Orders</h4>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script src="js/SendOrders.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all content those you want to refresh after download finished into UpdatePanel with `UpdateMode="Always"`

Comment: So youre saying put all labels/database tables into that updatePanel?

Comment: Could you clarify, what is database tables you are mean?

Comment: I apologize, I ment a gridview.

Comment: Yes, since you handle click event of button in an UpdatePanel you need   put all controls those you want to refresh into the same UpdatePanel or in an another with UpdateMode Always or set on that UpdatePanel "Conditional" UpdateMode and call Update method on it explicitly in the `Button_Click` method.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! I knew it was something simple!